# Angular JS and Print ngclick breaking page

Tags: angularjs

I have a print link like this

```
<div class="col-xs-3 mob-hide"> 
    <a href ng-click="$event.preventDefault();print('printableArea')" 
            class="share-icon print-cell">
    <img src="images/Print-Icon.png" alt="Print">Print</a> 
</div>
```

And Function

to print like this

```
$scope.print = function(print){
  var printContents = document.getElementById(print).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
};
```

it seems to load my print screen right, but when I hit cancel my screen loads again but none of the links on the page seem to work as before. For example my ng-click for the print function will not load again

Comment: You are manipulating the DOM to manage a print template. Can't you achieve the same results with a print stylesheet, where you display:none; everything that is not #print? This way your directive can call window.print(); only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

print.css

```
 * { display: none; }
 #print { display: block; }
```

directive

```
$scope.print = function(print){
  window.print();
};
```